# StackView trailing margin set to layout.trailing is not working

Tags: swift, layout, storyboard

I have a main StackView with the layout aligned to the layout guide. The views look fine in the storyboard, but when I build it to my iPhone SE (2nd Gen) the views within the StackView hang off the side of the screen.

I also have the issue of the top status bar appearing under the Nav bar and create chart button is cut off by the bottom which is also in the main StackView

Here are screen shots of what it looks like on the storyboard then iPhone:

[image: Storyboard SS]

iPhone SE Screen shot:

[image: iPhone SE SS]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the layout issue by changing the storyboard "view as: iPhone 11 Pro Max" setting to "view as: iPhone SE (2nd Gen)" which showed the constraints that conflicted with the SE screen size.

After deleting and adjusting some constraints it was resolved.

[image]